# Question on irreducible polynomials and primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, exponentiation, binary, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial $p(x) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^d a_i x^i$ where $a_i$ is binary and not all $a_i$ are $0$.
Is it possible that $p(2^n)$ is prime for all integer $n>-1 ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Let $q = p(1) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^d a_i$.  Take $n$ so that $2^n \equiv 1 \mod q$ and you have $p(2^n) \equiv 0 \mod q$.

Comment: What if $q$ is even, so no such $n$ exists?

Comment: q cannot be even , remember f(0)= prime. unless q = 2 , that gives fermat primes !

Comment: @Robert Thanks ! Do you know other cases of $n$ that fail ?

Comment: Actually not (just) Fermat primes: $1 + 2^{nk}$ is divisible by $1 + 2^k$ whenever $n$ is odd.

Comment: I was pointing out the connection to fermat primes only.

Comment: More generally, if $q | p(b)$ and $2^n \equiv b \mod q$ we get $p(2^n) \equiv p(b) \equiv 0 \mod q$. In particular try $b = 2^k$ (this time you don't have to worry about even primes).

Comment: Excellent ! @RobertIsrael +1